# First time app launch PageView

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uipageviewcontroller

I Have an `UIPageView` as first time welcome view, with a little help of [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/).

The middle view is the `PageContentViewController` and the last the RootViewController is called `PageViewController`.

[image]

Now I want to connect it with the NSUserDefault, which i did in the regulair first screen Controller:

```
- (void)Loadview_afterdelay
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])
    {
        PageViewController *intro = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        intro.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical ;
        [self presentModalViewController:intro animated:YES];

        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And in the ViewDidLoad of my RootViewController in the app:

`[self performSelector:@selector(Loadview_afterdelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`

I know that the `PageViewController` is the screen where I need to go.
When I try to do this the above way I get a crash:

`-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and locate the exact line where you are getting the crash.  It seems unlikely that it is in the code you have listed

Comment: Allready found the issue Paul, thanks to you're tip! Had to change the presentModalViewController: method to: `PageViewController *intro = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstPageViewController"];
        [self presentModalViewController:intro animated:YES];`